# changing togglebutton's state crashes app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, button, toggle

I have an app in Android-Kotlin that uses a toggle button. This app connects to other devices using the app so you could have two devices that have a toggle button. When the toggle button is pressed it will change the background color (simple). When one device presses the toggle button the setOnClickListener is triggered causing the background to change and the state of the toggle button to change as well. However, the other device notices that the other toggle button was pressed so it will change its background, but since the setOnClickListener was not actually called it does not change the state of the toggle button so it would remain in the on state while the other was in the off state.
I hav tried to programmatically change the state of the toggle button on the second device (The device that didnt actually have its toggle button pressed), but when i do
`toggleButton.setChecked(true)` or `toggleButton.isChecked = true`
my app crashes

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton)
        this.toggleButton.setOnClickListener {
           toggleLight(toggleButton.isChecked)
        }
    }
```

```
   private fun toggleLight(isOff: Boolean) {
        if(isOff) {
            this.mLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
            this.toggleButton.isChecked = true
        }
        else 
        {
            this.mLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            this.toggleButton.isChecked = false
        }
    }
```

```
2022-07-27 21:56:14.020 5513-5513/? I/ditto.moodligh: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-07-27 21:56:14.056 5513-5513/? D/ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
2022-07-27 21:56:14.084 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:4432): avc: granted { execute } for path="/data/data/live.ditto.moodlight/code_cache/startup_agents/50cdcce7-agent.so" dev="dm-34" ino=43151 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c161,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c161,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file app=live.ditto.moodlight
2022-07-27 21:56:14.089 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight V/studio.deploy: Startup agent attached to VM
2022-07-27 21:56:14.089 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight V/studio.deploy: No existing instrumentation found. Loading instrumentation from instruments-88564b4d.jar
2022-07-27 21:56:14.091 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight W/ditto.moodligh: DexFile /data/data/live.ditto.moodlight/code_cache/.studio/instruments-88564b4d.jar is in boot class path but is not in a known location
2022-07-27 21:56:14.093 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight V/studio.deploy: Applying transforms with cached classes
2022-07-27 21:56:14.103 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight W/ditto.moodligh: Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of java.lang.Thread java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been compiled.
2022-07-27 21:56:14.103 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight W/ditto.moodligh: Redefining intrinsic method boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected use of the original definition of boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been compiled.
2022-07-27 21:56:14.107 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171979766; UID 10161; state: ENABLED
2022-07-27 21:56:14.131 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight W/ditto.moodligh: ClassLoaderContext classpath size mismatch. expected=0, found=1 (PCL[] | PCL[/data/data/live.ditto.moodlight/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex*4229793514])
2022-07-27 21:56:14.147 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE Developer option for 'live.ditto.moodlight' set to: 'default'
2022-07-27 21:56:14.148 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight V/GraphicsEnvironment: ANGLE GameManagerService for live.ditto.moodlight: false
2022-07-27 21:56:14.148 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight V/GraphicsEnvironment: Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2022-07-27 21:56:14.154 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-07-27 21:56:14.155 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-07-27 21:56:14.247 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight W/ditto.moodligh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2022-07-27 21:56:14.248 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight W/ditto.moodligh: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
2022-07-27 21:56:14.365 5513-5545/live.ditto.moodlight D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 191844585; UID 10161; state: ENABLED
2022-07-27 21:56:15.451 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-07-27 21:56:15.454 5513-5526/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=9 mScannerId=0
2022-07-27 21:56:15.458 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGattServer: registerCallback()
2022-07-27 21:56:15.459 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGattServer: registerCallback() - UUID=3eb33987-3169-4d97-aba1-d3a8e3d47394
2022-07-27 21:56:15.461 5513-5526/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGattServer: onServerRegistered() - status=0 serverIf=10
2022-07-27 21:56:15.462 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGattServer: addService() - service: 331dcaa1-3995-83e8-090a-63787dc81031
2022-07-27 21:56:15.465 5513-5526/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGattServer: onServiceAdded() - handle=40 uuid=331dcaa1-3995-83e8-090a-63787dc81031 status=0
2022-07-27 21:56:15.473 5513-5572/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothAdapter: listenUsingInsecureL2capChannel: set assigned PSM to 140
2022-07-27 21:56:15.504 5513-5532/live.ditto.moodlight I/AdrenoGLES-0: QUALCOMM build                   : 781e7d0, I46ff5fc46f
    Build Date                       : 12/01/20
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.31.04.01
    Local Branch                     : QPR1
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Remote Branch                    : 
    Reconstruct Branch               : 
2022-07-27 21:56:15.504 5513-5532/live.ditto.moodlight I/AdrenoGLES-0: Build Config                     : C P 11.0.1 AArch64
2022-07-27 21:56:15.504 5513-5532/live.ditto.moodlight I/AdrenoGLES-0: Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2022-07-27 21:56:15.509 5513-5532/live.ditto.moodlight I/AdrenoGLES-0: PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
2022-07-27 21:56:15.512 5513-5532/live.ditto.moodlight W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID_from_sysfs:197>: Failed to open /sys/class/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/gpu_model
2022-07-27 21:56:15.512 5513-5532/live.ditto.moodlight W/AdrenoUtils: <ReadGpuID:221>: Failed to read chip ID from gpu_model. Fallback to use the GSL path
2022-07-27 21:56:15.513 5513-5532/live.ditto.moodlight D/hw-ProcessState: Binder ioctl to enable oneway spam detection failed: Invalid argument
2022-07-27 21:56:15.524 5513-5573/live.ditto.moodlight I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-07-27 21:56:15.524 5513-5573/live.ditto.moodlight W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-07-27 21:56:15.526 5513-5573/live.ditto.moodlight W/Gralloc4: allocator 4.x is not supported
2022-07-27 21:56:15.526 5513-5573/live.ditto.moodlight W/Gralloc3: allocator 3.x is not supported
2022-07-27 21:56:15.550 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-07-27 21:56:15.551 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
2022-07-27 21:56:16.070 5513-5524/live.ditto.moodlight W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2022-07-27 21:56:18.240 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 4E:C6:4B:9C:88:45, auto: false
2022-07-27 21:56:18.240 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
2022-07-27 21:56:18.240 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=908f6917-e9d6-4660-8715-29931933209e
2022-07-27 21:56:18.245 5513-5528/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=11
2022-07-27 21:56:20.208 5513-5526/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=11 device=4E:C6:4B:9C:88:45
2022-07-27 21:56:20.209 5513-5528/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGattServer: onServerConnectionState() - status=0 serverIf=10 device=4E:C6:4B:9C:88:45
2022-07-27 21:56:20.210 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGatt: close()
2022-07-27 21:56:20.211 5513-5513/live.ditto.moodlight D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=11
2022-07-27 21:56:22.209 5513-5561/live.ditto.moodlight A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 5561 (Thread-16), pid 5513 (ditto.moodlight)
```

when the first device presses the toggle button it calls toggleLight. There is another part of the code that also calls toggleLight for the device that did not have its toggleButton pressed.

Any reason why I can't programmatically change the state of the toggleButton?

UPDATE: it seems to crash whenever I try to change the properties of the toggle button. Tried changing toggleButton.text = "off", but this cause a crash as well.

Comment: You should post the full stacktrace, that tells you what the error is and what caused it. Also if you're trying to sync state like this, I'd really recommend you push the actual state to listeners (even if it's just a `lightOn` boolean) instead of telling them to toggle whatever they currently think the state is. Instead of a `toggleLight` function, have a `setLight(on: Boolean)` function - your click listener can call that with `isOff` (i.e. if it's off, turn it on) and that function can push the new state to all the listeners (including the one that did the click) and update the displays

Comment: @cactustictacs Even if I pushed the new state that way I would still update the state of the other listeners with ```toggleButton.isChecked = ?``` correct?

Comment: The state is a source of absolute truth, it's not relative to anything. You're not saying "whatever you think the current light status is, invert it" - you're saying *here is what the light status is, everyone update to it*. Everyone gets the same information, everyone sets to the same state. There's no weird inconsistencies because someone happened to click their button at the exact moment an "invert" command came in, y'know? So yeah, you'd push the new state, everything would store it in `isOff` or whatever, and then they'd update to reflect that - `if (isOff) button.isChecked = false` etc

Comment: The idea with pushing the event is that it updates *all the listeners*, including the one that generated the event (the one that saw the button press). So when *anyone* generates an event with a new toggle state, *everyone* gets informed of that new state and updates to display it. What that means is you don't need any special logic for the one that saw the button press. It doesn't need to go "oh I need to send the event and also update my display" - it just sends the event, and as a result of that it sees the new state and updates the same way everyone else does! Keeps the logic simple

Comment: @cactustictacs Sorry, I think I've been starring at it too long.. Would you be able to share a simple code example of passing this event?

Comment: I don't know how you're communicating with "other devices" but you're apparently sending *something* to let them know they need to toggle their button - send a boolean for whether it should be explicitly on or off instead. If there's some central server or whatever that broadcasts this information, your originating device (the one where the button click happened) can just react to that broadcast. If it talks to each of the other devices directly, it can call its own "receiver" function (as though it's receiving an event from another device, updating in response) as part of that process

Comment: You haven't posted your crash logs so I have no clue why whatever you're doing now isn't working - I was just suggesting you pass an explicit on/off state to everything, it's safer than a toggle and relying on everything else to stay consistent. And having a "broadcast state" update event, and a separate "display current state" function that reacts to that event, just means you don't need special logic for the device with the click. It announces an update, everything displays that update. If that's complex don't worry about it - just make sure you pass an explicit state around!

Comment: @cactustictacs I just added the logs

Comment: super.oncreate() is not called? is this. is this a complete stacktrace?

Comment: @Muneesh I called it. I just omitted some line of code to simplify the snippet for this post. Yes, complete stracktrace.

Comment: If that's the complete error log, there's no exception being logged showing why the app crashed. There's also usually some more data after the `libc: Fatal signal` bit that tells you what was happening internally when it crashed - that can usually point to something. Without seeing that, I'd guess it's either a Bluetooth issue or something to do with the GPU. What I'd do first is remove the Bluetooth stuff from the equation - try toggling the button without contacting the other devices. If it works, it's not that. Also add some logging if there's no stacktrace, so you can tell where it breaks